# python LDAP modrdn cannot get it to work / Object class violation or SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, ldap, python-ldap

I'm a complete newbie on LDAP Python

I inherited an LDAP with quite a complex DN, something like this:

blaAnfType=AAA-BBB+blaAnfId=AAA-BBB+blaUser=xxxxx

When I try and change one of the LDAP entry that an RDN in the DN, I use modrdn

modrdn_s(dn, change, True/False)

I can't get the correct syntax for it to work, either I get Object Class Violation or Syntax Error or Unable to create modlist etc...

For the dn I use "blaAnfType=AAA-BBB+blaAnfId=AAA-BBB+blaUser=xxxxx" (If I put something wrong in there I get object not found so I know the DN is correct.

However, for the change, I'm stuck.

I've tried
"{'blfAnfType': 'ZZZ'}" - Object Class violation or Cannot be a Tuple or cannot be a dict etc.
'blfAntType=ZZZ'

So:

modrdn_s(dn as shown above, One of the above and others., True/False)
e.g.
#connection.modrdn_s('blaAnfType=AAA-BBB+blaAnfId=AAA-BBB+blaUser=xxxxx', 'blaAnfType=ZZZ', 1)

What exactly should I have in there for it to to be correct.

For adding and modifying entries I use modlist but I find no modlist for RDN so I'm just trying what I can think of.

Thanks in advance.